# Difference between Dates - Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, logic

Guys!

I need some help here. It's basically a logical question.

I have a Date of publication of an item.
Example: 10/12/2022

I need a function to calculate this date from now, with a few rules:
If the difference is less than an hour, returns string: "Published 15 minutes ago"
If the difference is less than a day, returns string: "Published 4 hours ago"
If the difference is greater than a day, returns string: "Published in 10/12/2022"

How can I do this?

Thanks a lot for you help!

private fun calculateTime(date: Long): String {

return ""
}

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Certain questions here are more likely to get helpful answers. Questions that don’t show what you’ve tried are generally more difficult to answer - people often skip right over them. So show your code for better answers. If you encounter a specific technical problem during that attempt, we can help with that, and we want to - that’s part of why we’re here. To learn more about helping us help you, please start with [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). If you’re really ambitious, read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: Why is your date a long?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't actually use long as parameter but a temporal unit, the solution could look like this

```
fun calculateTime(date: Instant): String {
    val passedTime = Duration.between(date, Instant.now())
    return if (passedTime.toHours() < 1)
        "Published 15 minutes ago"
    else if (passedTime.toDays() < 1)
        "Published 4 hours ago"
    else {
        DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy")
            .withZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())
            .format(date)
    }
}
```